# Replace Printed Statement with timing sequence in C

Tags: c

I want to create a program to print out the first printf statement, Then in the next line, it will clear the first printf statement and print the next statement. Please help me fix the code.

```
printf("Please wait while Loading...");
Sleep(2132);
printf("Done Loading");
```

Comment: C only knows input and output **streams**, you can't modify what you already output! So, to achieve something like this, you'll need to use OS-specific APIs or a library abstracting them ([`curses`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) comes to mind). First think about whether you really need this.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? What goes wrong?

Comment: use return carriage. `\r`

Comment: @Wreigh this depends on the output device, so I wouldn't advice this.

Comment: One not foolproof method could be `printf("Loading...."); fflush(stdout); sleep(t); printf("\rDone Loading                                              \n");`

Comment: Ok, revising my comments: C indeed specifies `\r`, so **if** the output device is capable to jump to the beginning of the same line, this must happen on `\r`. Probably good enough for this scenario!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `stdout` is a terminal or window that supports overwriting of text, then the simple solution is to output a `'\r'` (carriage return), overwrite with spaces, and then print the second string.

```
printf("Please wait while Loading...");
fflush(stdout);
Sleep(2132);
printf("\r");
  /*  output the number of space characters equal to length of the preceding string */
printf("\r");
printf("Done Loading");
fflush(stdout);
```

There is the problem that not all terminals/windows support this correctly.  In that case, you'll need to use techniques specific to the terminal/window and host system.    This approach may also not work if standard output has been redirected to a file or pipe.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
printf("Please wait while Loading...");
fflush(stdout);    // flush output, this is necessary on some platforms,
                  // otherwise the text won't be printed immediately
Sleep(2132);
printf("\rDone Loading               \n");  // the \r returns to the start of the line, 
                                            // and the trailing spaces are necessary to
                                            // erase the remaining text
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not specific to C (or any other language for that matter), but to the *console* that you're printing to.

Many consoles understand the *carriage return* (`\r`) character to move the cursor to the beginning of the *current line*. You can try using that and "erase" the last message with spaces:

```
printf("Please wait while Loading...");
Sleep(1000);
printf("\r                            ");
printf("\rDone Loading\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pedantically you can't to what you want at least not in portable C99 or C11. BTW `sleep` is not standard C (but in  POSIX). You probably want some operating system specific stuff. I hope your are using Linux.

The stdio (i.e. `<stdio.h>` from standard C) only defines a limited notion of [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and standard output, much simpler than [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator).

(for example on Linux your program might be used in some command [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) , something like `yourprogram | grep foo | less` then  what you want is meaningless).

If you want to write a terminal-based application with a [text-based interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface), use a library for that. On Linux and POSIX it would be [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). Or you could use some [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)s and/or in some limited cases the return character `\r`. Remember that stdio is buffered, so you might need [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html). Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

You might even want to code a [graphical user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface). This should be thought at design phase (because your program needs some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) so would have a different architecture). Then use a [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) like e.g. [GTK](http://gtk.org/).

Comment: The behaviour of `\r` is documented in the standard though, though overwriting has undefined behaviour by omission ( :) ) presumably so that a line printer can be supported for the `stdout`

Comment: But if you run on Linux `someprogramwritingcarriagereturn | less` you often would be disappointed